# send data in postman body through postman other than sending parameters in http request url

Tags: json, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, lumen, lumen-5.4

i am working with Lumen Api Development and currently i am sending data in   request, that sending parameters in url. Now i want to send parameters in body and getting confuse how to send parameters in body.Need Your Help!

currently i am sending like this in URL as shown in image

[image: currently i am sending like this in URL]

Comment: Go to the body tab ->  if you want to post fields then use form data in which you have to specify key value pairs. If you want to post json data then use the raw tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on 'Body' and attach it in whichever form you deem right, raw, JSON, txt etc.